# Accessing AppDelegate object properties

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, properties, uiapplicationdelegate

How organize accessing to properties MyAppDelegate object for MyClass (ex: MyViewController). Can i directory get its from MyAppDelegate or i should pass it to init method as argument or  other?

Comment: Please rephrase your question, it's not really clear to me what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do... Passing objects that are usefull for other classes is a good idea. But if you really want to access one of your AppDelegate property, define (for convenience) :

```
#define MY_APPDELEGATE ((YourAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate)
```

Then access your property like this :

```
MY_APPDELEGATE.myproperty
```